# Radio buttons are not displaying on vf page

Tags: visualforce, class, radio-button

Here is the VF page:

```
<apex:page controller="rateQuestionsControllers">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:pageblockTable value="{!rateWrappers}" var="sWrapper">
                <!-- reference the sObject in the wrapper and get its name -->
                <apex:column value="{!sWrapper.theRatingRecord.Name}" />
                <apex:column headerValue="Rate">
                    <!-- where we are going to store this row's selected proficiency -->
                    <apex:selectRadio value="{!sWrapper.rating}">
                        <apex:selectOptions value="{!RatingSelected}" /> 
                    </apex:selectRadio>
                </apex:column>
            </apex:pageblockTable>
        </apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:pageBlock >

        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

This is the controller:

```
Public Class rateQuestionsControllers{
public class rateWrapper{
public Customer_Rating__c theRatingRecord{get;set;}
public Integer rating { get; set; }
}

public List<rateWrapper> rateWrappers { get; set; } 

public rateQuestionsControllers(){
     // new up the list for the wrappers
       rateWrappers = new List<rateWrapper>();
 for (Customer_Rating__c rate : [SELECT Id, Name FROM     Customer_Rating__c]) {
            rateWrapper sWrapper = new rateWrapper();
            sWrapper.theRatingRecord = rate;
            sWrapper.rating = 0; // a default selection (blank)
        }
}


public List<SelectOption> getRatingSelected() {

        List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();

        options.add(new SelectOption('bad','0'));

        options.add(new SelectOption('good','5'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('Excellent','10'));

        return options;
}

    public PageReference submit() {

     List<Customer_Rating__c> ratedetailslist = new List<Customer_Rating__c>()
        for (rateWrapper sWrapper: rateWrappers) {

            // only do the work if a value was selected
            if (sWrapper.rating!= 0) {
                Customer_Rating__c cr = new Customer_Rating__c();
                cr.Customer_name__c = sWrapper.theRatingRecord.Id;
                cr.Rating__c = sWrapper.rating;
                ratedetailslist.add(cr);    
            }

        }
        system.debug('-----rate---'+ratedetailslist);
        insert ratedetailslist;
        return null;
    }


}
```

Comment: `public Integer rating { get; set; }` make this String variable`public String rating { get; set; }`
then `sWrapper.rating = 0;` change this to `sWrapper.rating = '0';`

Comment: This not worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not added your rateWrapper to its list inside the constructor.

```
public rateQuestionsControllers(){
         // new up the list for the wrappers
     rateWrappers = new List<rateWrapper>();
     for (Customer_Rating__c rate : [SELECT Id, Name FROM Customer_Rating__c]) {
                rateWrapper sWrapper = new rateWrapper();
                sWrapper.theRatingRecord = rate;
                sWrapper.rating = 0; // a default selection (blank)
          rateWrappers.add(sWrapper);
        }
}
```

Comment: Still radio buttons are not visible

Comment: Do you have have Customer rating records in your org. What output you are getting with this code? The code with above modification works for me.